# Why would validation loss be exceptionally high while fitting with efficientnet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train with efficientnet on keras, following somewhat their tutorial on transfer learning [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/). But the validation losses are super high (more epochs show the same behavior), and go up and down, with accuracy not improving

```
effnet = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', input_shape = (224, 336, 3), include_top=False)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape = (224, 336, 3))
x = effnet(inputs, training=False)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(12, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

train_dir = 'train_images'
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split = 0.3)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        train,
        directory = train_dir,
        x_col = 'image',
        y_col = 'labels',
        target_size = (224, 336), 
        batch_size = 16,
        class_mode = 'categorical', subset='training')

valid_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        train,
        directory = train_dir,
        x_col = 'image',
        y_col = 'labels',
        target_size = (224, 336),
        batch_size = 16,
        class_mode ='categorical', subset='validation')

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=3, verbose=2, validation_data = valid_generator)
```

Which shows

```
Epoch 1/3
932/932 - 2285s - loss: 2.0492 - accuracy: 0.2466 - val_loss: 10590.5576 - val_accuracy: 0.1487
Epoch 2/3
932/932 - 2305s - loss: 1.9277 - accuracy: 0.2576 - val_loss: 255.5423 - val_accuracy: 0.1487
Epoch 3/3
932/932 - 2305s - loss: 1.9053 - accuracy: 0.2608 - val_loss: 257663.1406 - val_accuracy: 0.0075
```

Any ideas on why the validation loss could be so high?

Comment: Have you import from this `from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0`?

Comment: yes from there.

Comment: I noticed that the tutorial says, "the input data should range [0, 255]. Normalization is included as part of the model." though I rescaled it, but in any case, I don't see why train loss would decrease but not validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is some issue or bug in the original efficientnet and I don't know if it fixed or not yet. GitHub [Issue #48103](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48103)

A quick solution is to remove the following normalization:

```
rescale = 1./255,
```

Or, instead, use the unofficial efficientnet.

```
# Install non-official efficient network 
!pip install -U git+https://github.com/qubvel/efficientnet

import efficientnet.keras as efn 
base_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False,
                                        weights="imagenet", 
                                        input_shape=input_shape)
```